# Why does Rails 6 (and likely others) treat / path differently with regard to RoutingErrors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Say you have the following in your routes.rb (in rails 6.0.2.1):

```
root to: "healthchecks#index"
...
match '*not_found', to: 'exceptions#routing_error', via: :all
```

Say you have the following exceptions_controller:

```
class ExceptionsController < ApplicationController
  def routing_error
    request_description = "[#{request.method}] \"#{request.original_fullpath}\""
    Rails.logger.debug { "Routing Error: No route matches #{request_description}." }

    render json: { success: false, message: 'Not found' }, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

Now execute this curl:

```
curl -k -X POST https://localhost:3000/
```

In addition to 404 (from exceptions controller), you'll get FATAL logs about a routing error

Now execute this curl:

```
curl -k -X POST https://localhost:3000/foobar
```

Exceptions controller handles this route correctly and no routing error.

It seems Rails is treating the root path differently.  (works with 'root' or 'get' in routes.rb)